# How do I integrate my linux sonarqube scanner cli with Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I have installed the SonarQube extension in VSTS, configured it with my SonarQube server, username, and token, and created a task to perform a sonarqube cli analysis. However, when I get to the task in my build, I get the error message that it is not compatible with my operating system. Is this due to my build agent being Linux? Is there a way to get the SonarQube cli extension to use the SonarQube scanner for Linux rather than SonarQube scanner for windows?

Answer (score 1):

The incompatibility is indeed that you're trying to analyze .NET from Linux. The SonarQube Scanners are not yet compatible with that combination.